# Can outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CallBack) work for multiple mail account?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

> How can I add a listener to **All** or **Multiple** Mail Accounts?
> Or listen for all incoming mail before it is placed in a folder or
> subfolder?
>
> I am unable to create**outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CallBack)**  callback function for **multiple** account.

```
        Outlook.Application outlookApp;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder deleterFolder = null;
        Outlook.Items mailItems = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Outlook.Items items;
    
        private void Phishing_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {   
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

            inboxFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            deleterFolder = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);
            mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;//.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
            mailItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);
            items = inboxFolder.Items;
            items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CallFunction);
        }
 private void CallFunction(object data)
         {
       Console.Write(" Call Function");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a wrapper class that contains a pointer to the Items object (to keep it alive) and has a handler for the ItemAdd event. In your code you can have a list of these wrapper objects. Create a new instance of thatclass and add it to the list for each folder you want to monitor.

Off the top of my head:

```
public class ItemsWrapper
{
  private Items _items;
  private MAPIFolder _folder;
  public ItemsWrapper(MAPIFolder folder)
  {
    _folder = folder;
    _items = folder.Items;
    _items.ItemAdd += Item_Add;
  }
  private Items_Add(object item)
  {
    MessageBox.Show($"New item in folder '{folder.Name}' ");
  }
}

...
//global/class variable that will hold the wrappers
List<ItemsWrapper> allWrappers = new List<ItemsWrapper>();
foreach (MAPIFolder folder in FoldersThatYouWantToProcess)
{
  ItemsWrapper wrapper = new ItemsWrapper(folder);
  allWrappers.Add(wrapper);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am not understanding your answer you have any code examples, If  you have then attached the code please

Comment: I do not have a ready to run sample. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: In your code you can have a list of these wrapper objects. Create a new instance of that class and add it to the list for each folder you want to monitor. this part i am not understand and how it work for multiple outlook accounts? @Dmitry Strblechenko

Comment: not great to have non-functioning code as an answer.

Comment: The code above does not deal with accounts - it deals with MAPIFolder objects. Whether they come from the same account or different accounts is irrelevant. Are you having problems opening folders from multiple accounts? Then it is a totally different question.